# Convert xml string using Jackson to xml string in pretty format

Tags: java, xml, jackson, pretty-print

I used Jackson to convert XML string to map and back to XML String with pretty format but the final output didn't match the input 100%.

See the code below:

```
    @Test
    public void TestXmlStringToPretty() throws JsonMappingException, JsonProcessingException {
        String XML_STRING = "<SimpleBean><x>1</x><y>2</y></SimpleBean>";
        Map <?,?> map = xmlMapper.readValue(XML_STRING, Map.class);
        System.out.println(xmlMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(map));
        assertNotNull(map);
    }
```

The out is showing as follows:

```
<LinkedHashMap>
  <x>1</x>
  <y>2</y>
</LinkedHashMap>
```

How to convert XML string to a pretty format without losing the original structure?

Answer (score 1):

You need a Java class that corresponds to the XML Schema for deserialization as follows :

```
public class SimpleBean {

    private int x;
    private int y;
}
```

And here's your test method :

```
 @Test
    public void TestXmlStringToPretty() throws JsonMappingException, JsonProcessingException {
        String XML_STRING = "<SimpleBean><x>1</x><y>2</y></SimpleBean>";
        SimpleBean simpleBean = xmlMapper.readValue(XML_STRING, SimpleBean.class);
        System.out.println(xmlMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(simpleBean));
        assertNotNull(simpleBean);
    }
```

Comment: That's good, but what if I don't know the XML Structure? How I can create a generic class to match any input XML string including the name of the root node?

Comment: Probably this [link](https://gist.github.com/itavero/5858958) would help you.